Varicon Capacitor
I'm making a part list to build a AM/FM radio.  The schematic was published by Phillips Electronics in 1994 (see https://electronics-diy.com/pdf/TEA5711.pdf). My first question involves a capacitor that is described (page 21) as
C1
VARICON AM: 140/82 pF
FM: 2 × 20 pF
trimmer: 4 × 8 pF
TOKO type number HU-22124
The schematic diagram (pictured) seems to differ slightly. I've tried to Google "Varicon" and don't find good answers.  So here are my questions:
a) What is a varicon capacitor?
b) What is meant by 140/82 pF and FM: 2 × 20 pF?
c) What is meant by trimmer: 4 × 8 pF?
d) Are these actually drawn in or is there something that I am supposed to do with the above information?
e) I can't seem to find much information on TOKO type number HU-22124.  Is this a product/component?  If so, does this component ordered by the above?  Where can I order this part from (I'm in the USA).
I do have more questions about this schematic.  But I'll post each question separately.
In advance, thanks for your help!


It's a mechanical variable capacitor with integral trimcaps. This was common years ago in radios. I doubt that Toko has made these in a very long time. There has not been a Philips semiconductor in almost 20 years and that chip is 30+ years old. A very long time for a consumer product chip. Here is more-or-less what they looked like (image from Aliexpress:

This is not exactly what you are looking for, just to be clear.
The integral trimcaps are adjusted from the screws on the back of the unit. The ones in the datasheet will have more pins because they have 4 variable capacitor sections rather than 2, since the Philips chip does AM/FM. Everything except L1..L4 and the three capacitors with values marked - 8.2/18/22pF - is internal to the variable capacitor. The dotted line indicates that the variable capacitors are ganged together and all change together with shaft rotation.

Shopping questions are explicitly off topic here. Possible sources for obsolete parts include auction websites and sometimes there are similar parts made in China and available from B2C websites. Or recover a part from an old product.
I doubt you're going to be able to find all the parts such as IF transformer cores and formers to successfully build this from the provided information unless you reverse engineer it to use available parts.

"Varicon" "TOKO type number HU-22124" is just a "component", variable capacitor like this one
It contains 4 variable capacitors (on the same axis),
2 for AM (140 pF and 82 pF) and 2 (2* 20 pF) for FM bands.
It contains also adjustable capacitors (4 trimmers), paralleled on each variable capacitor,
of 8 pF to adjust the "scaling" of the "oscillator/filters".
Probably, obsolete component.



b) What is meant by 140/82 pF and FM: 2 × 20 pF?

These are four variable capacitors, all ganged together on one shaft.
Capacitor values stated are maximum capacitance when the shaft is turned so that all capacitor plates are fully meshed. No minimum capacitance is stated

140 pf....used to resonate the AM ferrite rod at the AM radio station frequency.
82 pf ....used to set AM local oscillator frequency to (AM_freq + 455 kHz)
20 pf ....used to resonate an inductor to FM radio station frequency.
20 pf ....used to set FM local oscillator frequency to (FM + 10.7 MHz) or (FM - 10.7 MHz)

Some additional screwdriver-set trimmer capacitances might be included to trim for stations at the high-frequency end-of-the band(s). These are not ganged to the main shaft.
